# Java SMTP mail - Connection timed out Error

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail, smtpclient

I've been developing a program to send email from desktop based Java application.

The program works fine when I'm testing it with the Google SMTP Server (smtp.gmail.com), however when I tested it for other smtp server it generates an error -

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:
 smtp.collaborationhost.net, port: 465;
 nested exception is:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

I'm running the code in Eclipse.

Below is the code snippet -

```
public class Emailer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name = "Testing";

        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.collaborationhost.net");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, 
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("qwert@xyzcompany.com","*******");
                }
        });

        try
        {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("qwert@xyzcompany.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("testgmail.com"));     
            message.setSubject("Generic Mail Test from Eclipse !!!");
            message.setText("This is a Test Mail, sent from Local Eclipse System via Google SMTP server. \n\n" + "Regards, \n" + name + "." );
            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Message Sent !!!");
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if the exact same code works with another SMTP server, then it's probably not the code syntax. Check that you have access from the machine you are running from, valid email accounts, correct ports, etc...

Comment: all the props are correct? As it works with google, I think your problem is that you have a wrong port or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

This JavaMail FAQ entry will help you [debug connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).  In this case, I suspect the other server isn't using the same port as Gmail so you'll need to change your configuration.

Also, you can simplify your program by correcting some of these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).